# How can we know whether any view is used anymore or not

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find about views whether they are used anymore or not.
I have tried the below queries but not much helpful

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'


SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM your_database LIKE 'your_table';
```

Can anyone tell me how to find the views usage.

I am using InnoDB.

Comment: I think it will be better if you show us your input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` only if VIEW is used in `PROCEDURE,FUNCTION and TRIGGERS`, it will not work if VIEW is called any individual SELECT query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%view_name%';
```

Comment: What if VIEW is called any individual SELECT query?

Comment: Most of the views in our database are called with individual SELECT query, then how to find them?